# Downcast Rust Polars Series to Struct causes a panic

Tags: rust-polars

I am trying to decompose the example from the rust polars user-defined function [user guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/user-defined-functions/#combining-multiple-column-values) (slightly simplified to i32 only)

```
extern crate polars;

use polars::prelude::*;//{CsvReader, DataType, DataFrame, Series};
use polars::lazy::dsl;
use polars::lazy::dsl::Expr;

fn do_apply_dyadic(s: Series) -> Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError> {

    // my debug code
    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![s.clone()]);
    println!("{:?}", &df);

    // downcast to struct
    let ca = s.struct_()?;

    // get the fields as Series
    let s_a = &ca.fields()[0];
    let s_b = &ca.fields()[1];

    // downcast the `Series` to their known type
    let ca_a = s_a.i32()?;
    let ca_b = s_b.i32()?;

    // iterate both `ChunkedArrays`
    let out: Int32Chunked = ca_a
        .into_iter()
        .zip(ca_b)
        .map(|(opt_a, opt_b)| match (opt_a, opt_b) {
            (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(a + b), 
            _ => None,
        })  
        .collect();

    Ok(Some(out.into_series()))
}
```

And then something like this:

```
let out = df
    .lazy()
    .select([
        // pack to struct to get access to multiple fields in a custom `apply/map`
        as_struct(&[col("values"), col("ovalues")])
            .apply( do_apply_dyadic, GetOutput::default())
            .alias("solution_apply"),
    ])
    .collect()?;
println!("{}", out);
```

The example in the docs works fine, but in my version, when it gets to the `let ca = s.struct_()?` line, it panicks with the error:
`thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'assertion failed: any.is::<StructChunked>()', /root/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/polars-core-0.33.2/src/series/ops/downcast.rs:150:17`

My debug code reconstructs a valid df from the s: Series param...

```
Ok(shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ values    │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {10,10}   │
│ {7,7}     │
│ {1,1}     │
└───────────┘
```

It seems that anything that I do to operate on s: Series (eg. println) causes a panic.

All was working OK until a couple of months ago.

Here is my Cargo.toml (yes I am using dtype-struct):

```
[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.148"
polars = {version = "0.33.2", features = ["lazy", "dtype-struct"]}
ffi-convert = "0.6.1"
libloading = "*"
```

Any hint as to how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first ting that comes to mind is you should probably be using `as_struct(...).map` instead of `.apply` because you aren't doing any aggregation over groups.